# webrtc: RTCTrackEvent doesn't include transceiver when received via ontrack handler

Tags: javascript, webrtc

From [RTCTrackEvent](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtctrackevent):

> ```
> [Constructor(DOMString type, RTCTrackEventInit eventInitDict),
>  Exposed=Window]
> interface RTCTrackEvent : Event {
>     readonly attribute RTCRtpReceiver           receiver;
>     readonly attribute MediaStreamTrack         track;
>     [SameObject]
>     readonly attribute FrozenArray<MediaStream> streams;
>     readonly attribute RTCRtpTransceiver        transceiver;
> };
> ```

There's a `transceiver` member.

However, when I received a `track` event via `ontrack()` handler,
`transceiver` is not present.

I'm going to use the `transceiver` to show the remote track received.

Any ideas what's the recent way of showing remote tracks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transceiver is not anymore needed.

`addTrack()` generates a `track` event where the remote `ontrack()` handler will be triggered.

Remote `ontrack()` handler will just have to set the remote video src using the received track stream.

**CODE (gUM)**

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
   audio: true,
   video: true
}).then((stream) => {
   if (! vid.srcObject) {
      vid.srcObject = stream;
   }
   // this triggers track event to the remote peer
   pc.addTrack(stream.getVideoTracks()[0], stream);
}).catch(logError);
```

**CODE (ontrack() - remote)**

```
pc.ontrack = function(evt) { // "track" event received
   if (! remote_vid.srcObject) {
      remote_vid.srcObject = evt.streams[0];
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

transceivers are not implemented yet in most browsers. Only Firefox 59+ implements them already. But you don't need them as you get the track and its associated streams.

Comment: Can you share a link showing WebRTC supported features per browser?

Yes, you're right. Got it working using track and streams only.